# Interpreting timestamp format on iDRAC servers

Tags: dell, time, drac, timestamp

The timestamp format on the DELL iDRAC format I have is the following:

```
20160714195526.000000+000
20150325225105.000000+000
20150311200640.000000-300
```

How should I interpret it (I want to parse it to a timestamp object, e.g. get date, time and timezone out of it)?

Comment: What command generated that output?

Answer (score 2):

Baiscally this is: **YYYYMMDDhhmmss.Timezone**

- YYYY Year four digits
- MM month two digits, zero padded
- DD day two digits, zero padded
- hh hour of day, 24h-system, zero padded
- mm minutes, zero padded
- ss secondy, zero padded

The part behind "." is most probably the time zone in relation to UTC or GMT.